# frida-trace call method function

Tags: javascript, objective-c, frida

I would like to understand what is the difference between

```
-[SomeClass firstdata:]*
```

and

```
+[SomeClass seconddata]
```

What I don't understand is what is - and + are they referenced to classes/methods? How are they different.

Also I noticed in the first example there is ":" does that mean the function somedata takes an argument? I created a frida script to inject this into an app I am trying to reverse engineer but I am not able to call `SomeClass.firstData` but I was however able to call `SomeClass.seconddata()` it said `"eval is not a function"`

Comment: `-`/`+` That's indeed class method vs instance method. `:` is indeed indicating that's there is a parameter after it. Since `secondData` doesn't have them, it takes no param, so `SomeClass.secondData()` is possible. The first one should be: `SomeClass().firstdata(param1)`, or I don't know in JS to pass param to methods.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html